# AppComponent.html:1 ERROR Error: No provider for Http! at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-http

When viewing the console log, I am getting this error '*No provider for Http!
    at injectionError*', in my Angular 4 application when trying to use the Http module. My `app.module.ts` file is

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserComponent } from './components/user/user.component';

import { DataService } from './services/data.service';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
UserComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
HttpModule
],
providers: [DataService],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And my service file, 'data.service.ts' is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/Http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

constructor(public http: Http) {
console.log('Data service connected...');
}

getPosts() {
return this.http.get('https//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
.map(res => res.json());
}

}
```

As shown, I have included the HttpModule in the `app.module.ts` file. What else I'm I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you had typo in `data.service.ts`'s import `Http` statement `from` path,

Instead of

```
import { Http } from '@angular/Http';
```

it should be

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
```

Comment: However I am having another challenge. I am trying to send a get request to https//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts but angular is appending this URL to localhost. So the response is from http://localhost:4200/https//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts How do I solve this? Thanks